# How to put Collator compare inside a custom sorting for objects in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

I have a function that sorts objects. I want to use collator.compare and I am not sure how to put it inside the function or the way to use it. Here is the custom sorting function.

```
  compare: function(a,b) {
    if (a.name < b.name)
      return -1;
    if (a.name > b.name)
      return 1;
    return 0;
  },
```

I want to sort using collator

```
var objs = [{name: '1_Document', size: 40}, {name: '11_Document', size: 50}, {name: '2_Document', size: 60}];

var collator = new Intl.Collator(undefined, {numeric: true, sensitivity: 'base'});
objs.sort(compare)
```

And my goal is to use collator.compare inside the function, how can I achieve that?

Comment: Just use `collator.compare` inside custom comparator.

Comment: HOW? Do you mind to elaborate that a bit ?

Comment: You just take ANY answer from the linked question and use your `collator.compare` to compare objects' properties.